Tefillin -- Chabad for Sephardim
I am a Baal Teshuva who is now working to identify what I need to set as family traditions going forward. My wife and I decided to come into observance in 2016 and since then, I have just accepted the customs of those around me--mostly Chabad because I have lived in places with small communities but with a Chabad nearby. Since neither my or my wife's families were observant (secular for at least two-generations), we have NO idea what traditions we should be following.
I am mostly Sephardi/Mizrahi/Bukharian--with some Ashkenazi thrown in for good measure. A mutt of the diaspora as one of my friends says. Call it 30%/20%/20%/30% for round numbers.
I learned to put on tefillin from Chabad and my tefillin are Chabad-styled. I have read that Horav Ovadya and Horav B”tz Abba Shaul stated that it is okay for Sephardim to use Chabad tefillin. If that is the case--which hand-wrapping custom is followed--is it the same as Chabad or as most Sephardim?
Further, if anyone has any great advice on really locking down traditions for Baalei Teshuva when there is a mixed diasporan demographic--I would love to hear it.

Welcome to MiYodeya Boaz and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see here for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

The reason they say Chabad tefillin is ok is because they don't use the Taz compromise like other Ashkenazim.
Any way you wrap it is not a real problem. You should probably still follow your own custom, especially if you are in a sfardi synagogue.
